# Do "POST" requests return XML data?

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to understand when does the server return `XML` data vs `HTML` text data, and how come `responseXML` can return both? Is `XML` data returned only when making a `POST` request?

It's hard to actually test these, because I couldn't properly setup a PHP server, and making a `POST` request keeps returning `404 bad request`, but when I make a `GET` request, I always get the `HTML document` in the `responseText` property, but when I try to use `responseXML`, I get `null`. So, if `responseXML` can return either `HTML` or `XML`, why does it not return the `HTML document` then?

**Note**: Before you accuse me of not doing any research. Let me tell you that I have been doing research for the past 3 days, and the book I'm reading just doesn't clarify these differences, and does not explain what exactly is `XML` in the first place. It says that `XML` data needs to be parsed to be displayed as a text, but doesn't explain why. It's all very ambiguous. So, I would appreciate if someone could clarify things for me.

Comment: POST requests return XML data, if the backend server is configured to return XML data. Completely depends on the server you're talking to, there's no way of predicting the behavior otherwise. Also, it's worth noting that every input can change the behavior of the server. E.g. if you provide a query with a specific value, the server could also return a CSS file, instead of an HTML or XML one.

Comment: @Keimeno you could post your comment as an answer. You explained well!

Comment: @Keimeno and I voted up! cheers!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POST requests return XML data, if the backend server is configured to return XML data. Completely depends on the server you're talking to, there's no way of predicting the behavior otherwise. Also, it's worth noting that every input can change the behavior of the server. E.g. if you provide a query with a specific value, the server could also return a CSS file, instead of an HTML or XML one.

Comment: So both POST and GET can return XML data depending on the server side code itself?

Comment: What about the responseXML. Why does it say that it can receive both text and XML? If that's the case, why does it not return the HTML document when I'm making a GET request?

Comment: @definitelynotme You can if the server responds HTML instead of JSON or XML.

Comment: Yes, POST and GET could both return XML data. When talking about `responseXML`, you mean the property of the `XMLHttpRequest` class, right? `responseXML` only returns the HTML document, if the `content-type` header is set to `text/html`. You could override it's `content-type` with the `XMLHttpRequest.overrideMimeType()` function.
You can check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML) for more information about this class and it's properties.

Comment: I see, and do you mind telling me what exactly is an XML data? Is it like a JSON object, which is why it needs to be first parsed into a string to be displayed?

Comment: @definitelynotme here is an introduction of XML https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_whatis.asp

Comment: @Masood It seems that XML data is still a text. So then why does it needs to be parsed? It's always the small key details that are always omitted from these explanations.

Comment: Because it contains a specific format and we need to parse it into Javascript object format or any other language we use to get that data.

Comment: So, you're saying that, we have to first use `eval()` to parse the XML data into a JS object, and then extract the text from the object?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of getting HTML from server response using fetch API.

```
fetch('https://someweb.com/api/list').then(function (response) {
    // The API call was successful!
    return response.text();
}).then(function (html) {

    // Convert the HTML string into a document object
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

}).catch(function (err) {
    // There was an error
    console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but this is too complicated for me to understand. I haven't studied most of these yet. I have no problem getting HTML form a server response. I outlined my problems in my question.

Comment: @definitelynotme I know, but it is an example to make things a bit clear for you.